# How to encode list of 16 numbers in less than 2 bytes

Tags: c, encoding, memory-optimization

I need to convey information of availability of  16 items with their id(0-15) in a variable.

```
char item_availablity[16];
```

I can encode it with 2 bytes where every bit is mapped with one item id where `1` represents available and `0` represents unavailable
For ex `0000100010001000`
This number has information that Items with id `4`,`8`,`12` are available

**I need to encode this information by using less than 2 Bytes.**

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You simply can't encode 16 bits of information in less than 16 bits.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Yeah sure, simply use a ternary computer.

Comment: you could use compression (some kind of RLE eg.) - the average size could be brought down that way (but outliers will still be 2 bytes, or even more, depending on the compression overhead)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Just to clarify: The average size can only be brought down if some permutations are more common than others. And to get complete coverage for the whole input space, some outliers will *inevitably* be *strictly* larger than two bytes.

Comment: @Lundin Those would be trits then. While we're at it, let's just go up to a base-64 computer

Comment: @klutt : sure - in practice, my suggestion is most likely useless - it only really has theoretical value. But for theory's sake, you can eg. bring the average down by about 1 bit by leaving off trailing 0 bits (of course, in practice, you'd quickly lose that gain again by the framing you'd have to add due to the variable length encoding - but hey)

Comment: You could easily encode this in a single byte. Just use 16 bits/byte.

Comment: You can encode 16 numbers very easily into just one byte... the problems will occur when trying to retrieve the original data upon extraction ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell: That would not be what normally is understood by the word "encoding". What you mean is "(lossy) compression", aka "reduction".

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); why do you “need to encode this information by using less than 2 Bytes”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply:

No, you cannot. It's simply impossible to store 1 bit of information about 16 separate things in less than 16 bits. That is, in the general case.

An exception is if there are some restrictions. For instance, let's call the items `i_1, i_2 ... i_16`. If you know that `i_1` is available *if and only if* `i_2` also is available, then you can encode the availability about these two items in just one bit.

A more complicated example is that `i_1` is available iff `i_2` or `i_3` is available. Then you could store the availability for these three items in two bits.

But for the general case, nope, it's completely impossible.

Comment: No there is no such condition. All items are independent in availablity

Comment: @OmkarKekre Then, it's impossible. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to think out of the box here - If some items are more rare than others, you could use a variable length encoding so that, *on average*, it would take less than 16 bits to store the information. However, there will be combinations of availabilities where it would take more than 16 bits.